# Foreign key creation in one-to-one table-per-concrete-class structure

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

**TL;DR** How can I enforce the Hibernate schema creation to create a foreign key constraint in a table-per-concrete-class setup from `AbstractProperty.ownerId` to `Owner.ownerId` for the structure displayed below, without adding a `Owner` property to the `AbstractProperty`?

I'm working on a project where I have the following class structure:

[image: Class structure sample]

The `Owner` has a one-to-one mapping to an `AbstractProperty`, which is extended by the `ConcreteProperty` class (and others like `AnotherProperty`, but that's not really relevant for the rest of this question).

The `AbstractProperty` really has only one property, the `abstractPropertyId`. Therefor, we want to use the [table-per-concrete-class](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html_single/#inheritance-tableperconcrete) structure, ending up with the tables `Owner`, `ConcreteProperty`, and tables for the other `AbstractProperty` extending classes (`AnotherProperty`).

To this end, I created the following mapping for `Owner`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="com.example">
    <class name="Owner">
        <id name="ownerId">
            <generator class="identity"/>
        </id>
        <property name="ownerProperty"/>
        <one-to-one name="abstractProperty"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And for the `AbstractProperty`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="com.example">
    <class name="AbstractProperty" abstract="true">
        <id name="ownerId">
            <generator class="foreign">
                <param name="property">ownerId</param>
            </generator>
        </id>
        <union-subclass name="ConcreteProperty">
            <property name="concreteProperty"/>
        </union-subclass>
        <union-subclass name="AnotherProperty">
            <property name="anotherProperty"/>
        </union-subclass>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

This works.

However, and here is my question, using this mapping and having Hibernate create the schema for me (`<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>`), it does not create a foreign key constraint from the `ConcreteProperty.ownerId` database field to the `Owner.ownerId` field. It does when I create the inverse constrained one-to-one field from the `AbstractProperty` to `Owner` using this mapping for `AbstractProperty` (where the `owner` field is of type `Owner` in the `AbstractProperty` java class):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="com.example">
    <class name="AbstractProperty" abstract="true">
        <id name="ownerId">
            <generator class="foreign">
                <param name="property">ownerId</param>
            </generator>
        </id>
        <one-to-one name="owner" constrained="true"/>
        <union-subclass name="ConcreteProperty">
            <property name="concreteProperty"/>
        </union-subclass>
        <union-subclass name="AnotherProperty">
            <property name="anotherProperty"/>
        </union-subclass>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

How can I enforce the creation of a foreign key from `AbstractProperty.ownerId` to `Owner.ownerId` without this `Owner` field in my `AbstractProperty`?

Comment: Why would you expect/need that there is a DB column/reference from the `*Property` table to the `Owner` table? According to your scheme, I would say the only reference w/ foreign key in DB is from `Owner` table to *Property...

Comment: I can't set a foreign key from `Owner` to `abstractPropertyId`, because I wouldn't know which table (i.e. which `AbstractProperty` implementation) it references.

Comment: Not an actual answer, but a question on the 'Why' on the Why-What-How spectrum: Are you explicitly building an Entity-Attribute-Value model?

Comment: @drvdijk, We have implemented a similar thing and there is no way to create this without having this <one-to-one name="owner" constrained="true"/> in Abstractproperty.hbm.xml. I looked at our code which is 4-5 years old and this is exactly what we have done.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: Never let Hibernate create the schema for real applications.

Hibernate is an object relational mapper and one should treat it as this.

That Hibernate additionally creates schemas is at most kind for the first time. But in environments after the first release you don't want to have Hibernate control over the schema. After all you have to handle SQL to have migrations scripts (manually or tool support). After the first release you will have data in the database. To ensure data migration on the production system with less problems you should consider schema and data migration the same way in the production environment as you do in your development environment.

Exceptions of that can be any application that has rarely changing data that may be reconstructable fast on data loss.

Answer (score 0):

We use standard JPA (no hibernate-specific hacks) and had the same problem, and we did not find a nice solution.

Assumptions:

1. `AbstractProperty` is a class in a package that is reusable/shared in different applications, and that you don't want a reference to an application specific `Owner` Class.
2. `ConcreteProperty` & `AnotherProperty` is application specific.

In this case, the solution would be to put references in `ConcreteProperty` to the `Owner` (with foreign keys), eventually both with `AnotherProperty` extending the same `ApplicationProperty`, and making the `abstractPropertyId` private, so that on setting the Owner, it is set automatically.

Comment: Do you mean `AbstractProperty` instead of `ApplicationProperty`? In my application I'd rather not have a reference to `Owner` at all to prevent solving cyclic serialization problems in a way I don't want to. Otherwise your solution would keep the `AbstractProperty` `Owner`-unaware, however you'd be copy-pasting the `Owner` getter and setter in all subclasses, something typically solved by the abstract super class.

Comment: No, I mean `ApplicationProperty` would just be another class (application specific) that extends `AbstractProperty` serving as a super type for all `Owner`-aware concrete classes (like `ConcreteProperty` and `AnotherProperty`)

Comment: Right, of course, nice! Unfortunately, it still doesn't solve my cyclic serialization problem, for which I simply cannot have an `Owner` in the `AbstractProperty` tree.

Comment: Also you could work in your ´Owner´ only with the ´Owner´-aware ´ApplicationProperty´ (which of course IS an ´AbstractProperty´) and so you could solve your serialization problem, isn't it?

Comment: That'd just introduce the `Owner`-unaware `AbstractProperty`, while the rest of the setup would be just as I have it now (my `AbstractProperty` being your `ApplicationPropery`). The problem is I serialize the `Owner` reflectively and recursively, which is why I'd rather have the unilateral relation from `Owner` to an `AbstractProperty`.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it work automatically if you define the Owner attribute on Abstract Property as "[transient](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.3)"?

> Variables may be marked transient to indicate that they are not part of the persistent state of an object.

And if you implement your own manual serialization you could check for the Modifier on a field and just ignore it --> cyclic serialization problem avoided.

The only other way I see is to push the Owner attribute to each of the concrete Property classes and change your mapping to

```
<class name="AbstractProperty" abstract="true">
    <id name="ownerId">
        <generator class="foreign">
            <param name="property">ownerId</param>
        </generator>
    </id>

    <union-subclass name="ConcreteProperty">
        <property name="concreteProperty"/>
        <one-to-one name="owner" constrained="true"/>
    </union-subclass>
    <union-subclass name="AnotherProperty">
        <property name="anotherProperty"/>
        <one-to-one name="owner" constrained="true"/>
    </union-subclass>
</class>
```

which creates the following sql:

```
create table AnotherProperty (
    ownerId integer not null,
    anotherProperty varchar(255),
    primary key (ownerId)
)

create table ConcreteProperty (
    ownerId integer not null,
    concreteProperty varchar(255),
    primary key (ownerId)
)

create table Owner (
    ownerId integer generated by default as identity,
    ownerProperty varchar(255),
    primary key (ownerId)
)

alter table AnotherProperty 
    add constraint FK_ceq89n6x2i1ax18bb4gqpq4m5 
    foreign key (ownerId) 
    references Owner

alter table ConcreteProperty 
    add constraint FK_i41buhvtxxtpsim2cc0ur1gxr 
    foreign key (ownerId) 
    references Owner
```

Comment: Actually, the database *should* store the property (with a foreign key), but it should not appear in the Java hierarchy because of the cyclic serialization. The `transient` keyword might actually do the trick though, maybe the serialization framework (trying to avoid writing manual custom stuff as much as possible) will ignore it while serializing, while I could still specify the property in the `hbm` files. Going to check it out, thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 0):

First : Hibernate/JPA is capable of handling a lot of scenarios - if there really was a lot of folks trying the same approach as you, I would think that it would have been addressed by now - it's no spring chicken.  ** that's a clue ;-) **

Second : Having a table called 'Owner' with a 'ownerProperty' is another clue.  The names infer a built in relationship.

Third : Simply by stating that you don't want an owner property within the AbstractProperty table, this sets the stage for a logical fallacy commonly referred to as a catch-22 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_dilemma).

My point -> This seems to be more of a modeling/design issue than a technical/framework issue.

My suggestion would be to take a step back from the problem, and re-evaluate it.  For example, if you were just writing straight queries with spring-jdbc, how would you expect to interact with the data for SELECT, UPDATE, and DELETE operations? ... if you work through those, your solution/needs would likely present themselves more clearly.  To be even more pointed, what would you expect the behavior to be on a cascading-delete?  If I issue a DELETE statement on a single Owner record, would you like for the database to automatically delete the records from the child tables? recursively?  Once you have that isolated, you can figure out how to tell Hibernate what to do - don't allow team members to put the cart before the horse by prematurely restricting the solution.

For example, (case 1 ) if you're really dealing with a 'property' of an owner, it would be reasonably foreseeable that you would need to store multiple properties about an owner (aka: OneToMany).

Alternatively, (case 2 ) if you're dealing with a 'type' of owner ( as in a discriminator field ), then your 'AbstractProperty' table should be extending Owner ... in which case you may be able to reduce your solution down to 3 tables ( Owner with a discriminator, Concrete1 w/ ownerId, Concrete2 w/ ownerId ).

Proposed Solution 1 : In either of those cases, it would still make sense for the 'AbstractProperty' table to have a reference to it's parent/Owner.  And if it did, I think Cascading DELETES may work the way that you would prefer.

Proposed Solution 2 : If however, in a cascading delete scenario of an Owner record, you would prefer that the row(s) in AbstractProperty stick around as reference-data, then it could be argued that you should put an additional table between Owner and AbstractProperty to protect your reference data ... as a mapping table that has a unique composite key.

Focus on the business needs and user-stories, and that should hopefully guide your choice of available solutions.